# tf listener does not see specified links in URDF file

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ur10, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i have been working with a UR10 and need to have the position of the TCP in real time.
In a previous post, people recommended me to build a TF listener and when i got that working i could indeed track the position. I still had some position errors in general and therefore i downloaded and installed the [Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver). But now, the TF_2 program does not seem to see links other then those specified by the original URDF of the UR10. I can see this when i echo the tf topic. I expect to see all links attached, but i only see the links that are defined in the URDF of the UR10. I find this really strange i get no errors and RVIZ does load all the links and elements that are specified. The moveit! setup assistant also loads all links.

I simply build the tf_listner from [this tutorial] (http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29) and switched the names of the link.
The links that i am missing should be attached to tool0 ans would go to a tool_tcp. Tool is the prefix i defined in the URDF. I also miss the table links who have the prefix table_

I only changed the default parameters to the parameters that i already have defined. Like the  ip adress of the robot.

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>   
    <launch>  
    <arg name="debug" default="false" doc="Debug flag that will get passed on to ur_common.launch"/>  
    <arg name="robot_ip" default = "10.242.15.81" doc="IP address by which the robot can be reached."/>   
    <arg name="reverse_port" default="50001" doc="Port that will be opened by the driver to allow direct communication between the driver and the robot controller."/>   
    <arg name="script_sender_port" default="50002" doc="The driver will offer an interface to receive the program's URScript on this port. If the robot cannot connect to this port, `External Control` will stop immediately."/>  
    <arg name="tf_prefix" default="" doc="tf_prefix used for the robot."/>   
    <arg name="controllers" default="joint_state_controller scaled_pos_traj_controller speed_scaling_state_controller force_torque_sensor_controller" doc="Controllers that are activated by default."/>  
    <arg name="stopped_controllers" default="pos_traj_controller" doc="Controllers that are initally loaded, but not started."/>  
    <arg name="controller_config_file" default="$(find ur_robot_driver)/config/ur10_controllers.yaml" doc="Config file used for defining the ROS-Control controllers."/>   
    <arg name="robot_description_file" default="$(find ur_description)/launch/ur10_upload.launch" doc="Robot description launch file."/>   
    <arg name="kinematics_config" default="$(find ur_description)/config/ur10_default.yaml" doc="Kinematics config file used for calibration correction. This will be used to verify the robot's calibration is matching the robot_description."/>  
    <arg name="limited" default="false" doc="Use the description in limited mode (Every axis rotates from -PI to PI)"/>   <arg name="headless_mode" default="false" doc="Automatically send URScript to robot to execute. On e-Series this does require the robot to be in 'remote-control' mode. With this, the URCap is not needed on the robot."/>   
    
    <include file="$(find ur_robot_driver)/launch/ur_common.launch">
        <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
        <arg name="use_tool_communication" value="false"/>
        <arg name="controller_config_file" value="$(arg controller_config_file)"/>
        <arg name="robot_description_file" value="$(arg robot_description_file)"/>
        <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
        <arg name="reverse_port" value="$(arg reverse_port)"/>
        <arg name="script_sender_port" value="$(arg script_sender_port)"/>
        <arg name="kinematics_config" value="$(arg kinematics_config)"/>
        <arg name="limited" value="$(arg limited)"/>
        <arg name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg tf_prefix)"/>
        <arg name="controllers" value="$(arg controllers)"/>
        <arg name="stopped_controllers" value="$(arg stopped_controllers)"/>
        <arg name="headless_mode" value="$(arg headless_mode)"/>   
</include> 
</launch>
```

I activate this file with the calibration file that is required.

my launch file for the moveit part is this

```
<launch>  
<arg name="sim" default="false" /> 
<arg name="limited" default="true"/>  
<arg name="debug" default="false" />  
<include file="$(find seallant_robot)/launch/planning_context.launch">  
<arg name = "load_robot_description" value = "true"/> 
 </include>  
<!-- Remap follow_joint_trajectory -->  
<remap if="$(arg sim)" from="/follow_joint_trajectory" to="/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory"/>  
<!-- Launch moveit -->  
<include file="$(find seallant_robot)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="limited" default="$(arg limited)"/>
    <arg name="debug" default="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="info" value="true"/>  </include>  <include file = "$(find seallant_robot)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/> 
</include>  
</launch>
```

Quick info: ROS kinetic, UR10, Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver, Ubuntu 16.04, [image: rqt_tf_tree]

if someone knows where to look for the problem, that would be awesome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343699/tf-listener-does-not-see-specified-links-in-urdf-file/) by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-10**:\

> the TF does not seem to see links other then those specified by the original URDF of the UR10

this is a little vague. "the TF" does not really exist.

Please post a `rqt_tf_tree` screenshot, a concrete example of some code that used to work but no longer does and show us how you start things (ie: which `.launch` files, etc).

Update your original question text with this information. Use the `edit` button/link to do that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-10**:
Could you check the formatting of your question? Some of the copy-pastes have turned out a bit jumbled.

General workflow:

1. paste a verbatim copy of the text you want to include
2. select it
3. press `ctrl+k` or click the *Preformatted Text* button (`101010`)

Do not just select the first line for step 2. Make sure to select all text you want to format.

> I simply build the tf_listner from [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(Python)) and switched the names of the links.

Yes, but *which* links. Names are important here.

> I made some slight modifications to the bringup file

please mention which changes.

And also please tell us what doesn't work. What sort of errors do you see?

> I can see this when i echo the tf topic

what do you see? What do you expect to see? Which transforms are missing?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:
We'll probably need to see how you added your EEF and "table links" to the URDF/Xacro.

`ur_robot_driver` uses a specific version of `ur_description` (and related packages) and it could be your modifications are no longer being loaded after you switched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason why the other links did not show up in the rqt_tf_tree was because i was only using the `robot description` of the ur10 and not the description of the entire robot. so this question can be closed as there is no issue.

---

Originally posted by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) with karma: 37 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0